# Scraping data from website that uses javascript

Tags: java, javascript, screen-scraping

I'm currently working on a program that checks University class availability but the website uses javascript to display classes and their times. Using Java, I'm working on scraping this data and using it to tell users when classes are open.

I've tried using Selenium but I do not really know how to use it very well. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Selenium is perfectly suited for this. please be more specific if you need help this the task

Comment: @luksch Sorry for being vague, I'm just not sure where to start. I'm not sure if I should be opening the page in a browser via Selenium or just scraping the data with it. I'm unfamiliar with website scraping as a whole so I apologize for my naivety.

Comment: what i do for more complex scraping jobs is using selenium to navigate to the page in question, do all the required clicks and then save the final page as string and use then JSoup to process it. This might be overkill in your situation, so you can try using selenium selectors to scrape directly.

Answer (score 0):

Without specific is hard to know. But I assume that if the data is not in the page at load time they may be using AJAX to load it.

As I said I may be assuming too much, but your question is vague, if they use AJAX, check the call they do (and get a json response with a bit of luck) and your work will be extremely easy.

Comment: I think I'm in a little over my head with this project but I believe that it is AJAX. Specifically, this is the source page view-source:http://sis.rutgers.edu/soc/#subjects%3Fsemester%3D92013%26campus%3DNB%26level%3DU

Comment: @MikeMelchione Open up the developer tools in your browser and activate the network tab, and you'll be able to see all the AJAX requests and the parameters that are passed, and you should be able to reverse engineer the calls you need to make.